# Cannot avoid Cython from compiling external C module in Python2.7 rather than Python3.x

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, shared-libraries, cython

This question is related to a couple of questions in SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603628/how-to-specify-python-3-source-in-cythons-setup-py) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115063/porting-cython-files-from-python2-to-python3-with-2to3). Unfortunately the solution there is not working for me so far. I have a `module.pxc` file which I am compiling by a `setup.py` file, such as the following one:

```
# setup.py

module_extension = Extension(
name="iolif",
sources=["/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/dcomplex_libc.c",
         "/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/special_functions_libc.c",
         "/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/models/freq_cv_libc.c",
         "module.pyx"],
libraries=['gsl', 'gslcblas', 'm'],
# library_dirs=["lib"],
include_dirs=["/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/pycustommodules",
              "/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries",
              "/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/models"]
)
setup(
    name="iolif",
    ext_modules=cythonize([module_extension])
)
```

From command line, in the same directory of `module.pxc`, when writing `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` compilation works fine, and the `iolif.so` library is produced. The issue is that I can only import this library if I use `Python2.7`, whereas if I attempt to import it in `Python3.x` I get the known `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_iolif)`.

Googling around, and as pointed out in the two questions linked above, it seems that this is due to the fact that `cython` is looking at `Python2.7` rather than `Python3.x` (which is the one I work with instead). Accordingly, I attempted asking `cythonize` in my `setup.py` to use `Python3.x` by:

```
...
setup(
    name="iolif",
    ext_modules=cythonize([module_extension],
                           compiler_directives={'language_level': "3"})
)
```

but it still does not work. The last compilation message indeed produces:

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now - 
specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pylif_io.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/dcomplex_libc.o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/special_functions_libc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/models/freq_cv_libc.o -L/usr/lib64 
-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lpython2.7 -o /home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/DePitta.PNAS/Software/LIF.Analysis/iolif.so
```

where you can see that it is still linking with the `-lpython2.7` library (whereas it should use for example `-lpython3.7m`). How do I solve it? What am I missing?

Comment: You should call setup.py with Python3 and not Python2. That is just how distutils work.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution. My `python` command was still associated with `python2.7` (I recently moved to `Python3.x`). Sorry about it. Hence:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

will make the trick. Indeed compilation now reads:

```
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/pylif_io.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/dcomplex_libc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/special_functions_libc.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/c_libraries/models/freq_cv_libc.o -L/usr/lib64 -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -lpython3.7m -o /home/maurizio/Ongoing.Projects/DePitta.PNAS/Software/LIF.Analysis/iolif.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

as required.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks. I thought so. But then it is not solving the issue. AR has not been provided for  Linux since ages. And other presentation-feidnly options like `pdfpc` won't work under GNOME. Plus Fedora 30+ uses Wayland which makes things even more complicated...